# C# Design Regarding Static Classes and Inheritence

Tags: c#, inheritance, static, abstract-class

I am designing a card game in C#. Each  card is an instance of the `Card` class that contains two properties: a unique ID for the card and a reference to a `CardData` object. The object of type `CardData` implements the methods regarding how the `Card` functions within the game rules. Many cards (ex. if there are multiple jack of clubs) can reference the same card data.

```
public class Card {
    public int id;
    public CardData card;
}
```

My question is regarding how I should implement the `CardData` class. My first instinct was to design an abstract base class `CardData` with a bunch of  methods like `WhenPlayed()` and `WhenRemoved()`, and then have a subclass for each card that implements them.

```
public abstract class CardData () {
    public abstract void WhenPlayed();
    public abstract void WhenRemoved();
}

public class JackOfClubs : CardData () {
    public override void WhenPlayed()  { 
        Console.WriteLine( "You played a Jack of Clubs!" );
    }
    public override void WhenRemoved() {
        Console.WriteLine( "Bye for now" );
    }
}
```

However, since I never want to actually instantiate a `JackOfClubs` object, but rather instantiate `Card`s and give them a reference to the `JackOfClubs` class, it would make sense to make the `CardData` class and all subclasses `static`. This creates a problem, because as far as I know static classes cannot inherit.

Furthermore, I considered using an `interface` but I wanted the possibility of default methods. For instance, if 90% of my `CardData` objects implement `WhenRemoved()` as "Bye for now", it would be tiresome to retype that for each subclass. I could use a non abstract `CardData` class to achieve this, but not an interface.

My question is what would be the best or correct approach to handling a class structure such as this, if there is one.

Comment: *"However, since I never want to actually instantiate a JackOfClubs object, but rather instantiate Cards and give them a reference to the JackOfClubs class, it would make sense to make the CardData class and all subclasses static."* You do instantiate `JackOfClubs`. If you didn't, you wouldn't be able to pass it to your `Card` object. I don't see how that would make it a good use for `static`.

Comment: I suppose you're right. So would a singleton approach make the most sense? I never want there to be multiple JackOfClubs, since the rules for each JackOfClubs are the same and multiple instantiations would be wasteful.

Comment: I would still make it an instance class, but only instantiate it once. Further, you can make `WhenRemoved` method `virtual` instead of `abstract`, and give it a default implementation.

Comment: [Here's a repository on github where someone has modeled the data structures for a card game using standard playing cards](https://github.com/ashfordl/cards).  It doesn't match the approach you described, but you might find it interesting regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a design like this[please refer the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar8iF.png), so that you don't create as many classes as there are many cards, essentially they are different objects of the same class. So we have factory that holds a custom collection called Cards which is a collection of Card class that has a type and value. You can implement the play method depending on the type and value o the card. In the case that you are playing a game where all the cards are not involved, this design just works fine, in the case that you are extending this to multiple card games, if you add one more class card category, this design encompasses that as well. Hope this helps.